# Select using case shows all results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Two fields in the table `articles`:

`title` and `body`

Two records:

`meow bark | 1234 5678` and `bird snake | 8596 2952`

Where `meow bark` is under `title` and `1234 5678` is under `body`, etc...

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN title = 'meow' then 1 else 0 end + CASE WHEN title = 'bark' then 1 else 0 end AS matches 
FROM  articles 
ORDER BY matches DESC
```

Returns both rows. Please help me understand what's wrong with my syntax. I am expecting it to return only rows where the title matches what is in the query. Unless I do not understand how CASE works, if title in the above example matches meow or bark, it should display - else, do not display.

The goal is to return results based on most matches. Take at fiddle look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13b33/10

I modified it slightly, didn't think enough to break it though.

Comment: ok - that is what is happening but what do you _want_ to be returned?

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the question

Comment: in the title field does it actually say 'meow bark' ...or does it say 'meow' **or** 'bark' ?

Comment: title would be "meow bark" without quotes. Essentially the point of this is to return results based on most matches. User could type a string that is exploded (via PHP) into 2 or more instances, then they're fed to SQL and results show (from top) of rows that have the "most" matches in their title to the searched keywords.. working down to those that have only one match

Comment: in the fiddle - can't really see what is wrong?!

Comment: some of those words are in each of the phrases so the fiddle returns all the records - what records do you want it to miss out?

Comment: Records which contain 0 matches to any of the words. Most matches desc

Comment: edited my answer with a fiddle [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e37c/9](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e37c/9) - you can add an `order by` to the end of that script

Comment: [A BETTER FIDDLE INCLUDING THE ORDER BY](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e37c/10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsure what you want to achieve ...what would you like to be returned

This might be a bit closer to what you want

```
SELECT *, 
       matches = CASE WHEN title LIKE '%meow5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN title LIKE '%bark5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  
FROM   articles 
ORDER BY matches desc
```

**EDIT** after OP has been updated

Try using the `WHERE` clause if you only want some of the records to be returned:

```
SELECT *
FROM   articles 
WHERE  title LIKE '%meow%' 
       OR 
       title LIKE '%bark%'
ORDER BY matches desc
```

**FINAL EDIT**

[Try this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e37c/10)

In case Fiddle goes out of date here is the script:

```
CREATE TABLE  YourTable (FieldToSearch varchar(max));
INSERT INTO YourTable 
VALUES
('If there were a dog'),
('If there was a dog'),
('If that dog died!'),
('I''d be happy with cat');

SELECT x.*
FROM   (
       SELECT FieldToSearch, 
       CASE WHEN ' ' + FieldToSearch + ' ' like '% if %' then 1 else 0 end
       + CASE WHEN ' ' + FieldToSearch + ' ' like '% there %' then 1 else 0 end 
       + CASE WHEN ' ' + FieldToSearch + ' ' like '% was %' then 1 else 0 end
       + CASE WHEN ' ' + FieldToSearch + ' ' like '% a %' then 1 else 0 end
       + CASE WHEN ' ' + FieldToSearch + ' ' like '% dog %' then 1 else 0 end AS matches
      FROM YourTable
      )x
WHERE x.matches >0
ORDER BY x.matches DESC;
```

Comment: +1 but you still need the matches expression in the second query in order to ORDER BY.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I've added a link to fiddle - I'll amend it now

Answer (score 3):

You need to put that in a WHERE clause rather than the SELECT clause if you want to exclude rows.

Also, the comparisons you are using are for *equivalence*. This will not "match" if the column contains your search value, as you seem to think, but only if the column *has exactly the same text and nothing else* (with some small allowances for collation).

Answer (score 0):

you dont have where clause mentioned in the query, it will fetch all the records unless you filter them using where condition